# Sum over few Product Categories

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to calculate the Life Premium as given in the below table. I want to calculate the sum only for rows where the product category like 'Life%' but apply it across all the rows where we have an occurrence of a 'Life' Product for a policy, for every other Policy (i.e. the ones where there is no 'Life' product it should be 0)

[image]

I tried the Sum(Cost) OVER (Product Sub Category) but it gives a value across all the Policies even the ones which don't have a Life Product.  Sadly the partition by clause doesn't allow a Where clause.

Can someone please help?

Comment: You should add your table structure, sample data and expected result in formatted text, not image.

Comment: Oh, thank you . My first post and thus :). Will keep in mind.

Comment: Great, let us know when you've fixed the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when productsubcategory like 'Life%' then cost else 0 end) over
           (partition by policy) as lifepremium
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you works like a charm, damn I knew it was easy! Just not my day. have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Case When`

Check this:-

```
Select a.*, case when a.policy=b.policy then Life_Premium else 0 end as Life_Premium   
from
table a
left join
(
select policy,sum(cost) as Life_Premium from TableA where product_sub_category  LIKE 'Life%'
group by policy
) b
on a.policy=b.policy;
```

Let me know if you have any questions